# Haar measure decomposition using orbital integrals

Tags: integration, p-adic-groups, haar-measure, conjugacy-classes

Let $G$ be a unimodular locally compact group, $N,A \le G$ be unimodular closed subgroups. Suppose that $A$ normalizes $N$. Let $N_0 \le N$ be a compact open subgroup. Suppose that a function $f : N \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is supported on $\bigcup_{a \in A} a N_0 a^{-1} $. Is there a formula to compute $$ \int_N f(x) dx $$in this case in terms of integration over $A$ and $N_0$?
For example, if $G$ is a finite group, we have
$$ \sum_{x \in N} f\left( x \right) = \sum_{a \in A} \sum_{x \in N_0} \frac{1}{\left| C_x \left( A \right) \right|}  f\left( a x a^{-1} \right),$$ where $$C_x\left( A \right) = \left\{ a \in A \mid ax=xa \right\}$$is the centralizer of $x$ in $A$.

I am interested in particular in the case where $G$ is a matrix group (over a non-Archimedean field), $N$ is a unipotent radical of a parabolic subgroup of $G$, and $A$ is a subgroup of the Levi part of the same parabolic subgroup.

Comment: I suspect that (assuming you are also willing to take $f$ locally constant and compactly supported, as usual in such applications) you'll have much better luck in your specific case than in general, because the orbit stratification is so much nicer.  I don't know off the top of my head even in that special case, though.

Comment: Actually, wait:  if $f$ is compactly supported, then, since a compact subset of $\operatorname{Int}(A)(N_0)$ is contained in $\operatorname{Int}(a)(N_0)$ for a specific $a \in A$, it's easy.  So maybe you don't want to assume compactly supported?

Comment: Yeah, $f$ in my case should not be compactly supported, but it is locally constant.

Comment: Aha.  Is there some other hypothesis that guarantees that $\int_N f(x)\mathrm dx$ converges?

Comment: (Actually I guess I just mean more generally, could you say some more about how this problem arises?  Orbital integrals on $p$-adic groups is pretty close to my research, and I might be able to say more if I knew the context.)

Comment: In short, I have some integral related to the generalized doubling construction for some representation, it depends on some section $f$. I am trying to construct a section of a different representation so that a similar integral will evaluate to the same value. I might email you more details if I have time to write it down. Thanks

Comment: Sure, [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/374122/haar-measure-decomposition-using-orbital-integrals#comment948228_374122)'d be fine.

Comment: I suspect that, under any reasonable hypothesis (including that any two dilates $a_1 N_0 a_1^{-1}$ and $a_2 N_0 a_2^{-1}$ are contained in a common dilate $a N_0 a^{-1}$), you could compute $\int_N f(x)\mathrm dx$ as $\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{N_0} f(a x a^{-1})\mathrm dx$, but presumably that's not the spirit of what you want.